# How to find top 10 elements in MapReduce

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to write a Python MapReduce job on some datasets I have to find certain statistics. This is a example of the input data and the form it comes in:

```
exchange, stock_symbol, date, stock_price_open,stock_price_high,stock_price_low, stock_price_close, stock_volume,stock_price_adj_close.
```

I need to use the find the top 10 days on which the most stock was traded which is calculated from: `stock_price_close * stock_volume`

Here is the code I have right now:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MapReduce(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        values = line.split(',')
        amount = int(float(values[6]) * float(values[7]))
        code = values[1]
        date = values[2]
        list = (code, date, amount)
        yield(None, list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MapReduce.run()
```

I'm having trouble implementing a Reducer method for this job however, and not sure how the Reducer will work and find the top 10 elements only. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: On the class MapReduce, create new attribute that could hold 10 items i.e. a list with 10 items, name it top_ten or something. You might have to manually restrict adding more than ten elements to this list. Filter function could calculate stock_price_close * stock_volume value and update the top_ten as required.

Comment: How much data are we talking. If it is not so much you could certainly do what you want by having a single reducer and using a combiner to reduce workload in your reducer combiner.

Answer (score 2):

Make this a [multi-step](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/writing-mrjobs.html#multi-step-jobs) job.  The end result of the first step is per day, the total amount traded.  The second gets the totals, sorts them, and returns the top 10.